# Powershell Compare text files and show differences

Tags: powershell

I need to do a file comparison and want to use Powershell. I need an output file listing all of the differences. The below is a good start, but I need the file to inlcude line numbers, and the resulting Input Object currently also gets cut off after 89 characters - I need the full line to display:

```
compare-object (get-content $File1) (get-content $File2) | Out-File $Location
```

Answer (score 17):

The Input Object is being truncated by the default display.  To save the entire line to a file:

```
compare-object (get-content $File1) (get-content $File2) | format-list | Out-File $Location
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$abc = gc .\z.txt | %{$i = 1} { new-object psobject -prop @{LineNum=$i;Text=$_}; $i++}
$cde = gc .\x.txt | %{$i = 1} { new-object psobject -prop @{LineNum=$i;Text=$_}; $i++}
Compare-Object $abc $cde -Property Text -PassThru -IncludeEqual
```

Try this for spitting out line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$apples = Get-Content D:\misc\1.txt
$oranges = Get-Content D:\misc\2.txt

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $apples -DifferenceObject $oranges -PassThru | Out-File D:\misc\mm.csv
```

Comment: The output of this command is correct, but it is missing the descriptive parts of the output so it fulfills the requirement to compare the files, but unlike some other answers it only partially fulfills the requirement to show the differences.

Answer (score 2):

I used this answer https://serverfault.com/a/951843. It provides a much more useful output in my point of view:

- Contains line numbers
- Is ordered by line numbers
- Is also only using powershell commands

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to save the entire line in a file

```
Compare-Object -referenceObject $(Get-Content $File1) -differenceObject $(Get-Content $File2) | %{$_.Inputobject + $_.SideIndicator} | ft -auto | out-file $Location -width 5000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result= Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content D:\demo\misc\1.txt) -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content D:\demo\misc\1.txt) | Select -Property InputObject 
$result.InputObject
```

Used above code to get difference of 2 files