# Comparing two text files is not working in Powershell

Tags: list, powershell, text, console, compare

I am trying to compare the contents of two text files and have only the differences be outputted to the console.

The first text file is based on the file names in a folder. 
`$AsyFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path .\asy-data -Name`

I then remove the prefix of the file name that is set up by the user and is the same for every file and is separated from the relevant info with a dash.

`$AsyFolder| ForEach-Object{$_.Split("-").Replace("$Prefix", "")} | Where-Object {$_}|Set-Content -Path .\templog.txt`

The output looks like [$Asyfolder Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ovZg.png)

```
bpm.art
gbr.pdf
asy.pdf
fab.pdf
as1.art
odb.tgz
ccam.cad
read_me_asy.txt
```

There is another file that is the reference and contains the suffixes of files that should be there. 
It looks like this [Reference File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXq2l.png)

```
tpm.art
bpm.art
gbr.pdf
asy.pdf
fab.pdf
as1.art
as2.art
odb.tgz
xyp.txt
ccam.cad
```

And its contents are received with `$AsyTemplate = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\asy_files.txt`
The logic is as follows

```
$AsyTemplate |
    ForEach-Object{
        If(Select-String -Path .\templog.txt -Pattern $_  -NotMatch -Quiet){
           Write-Host "$($_)" 
        }

    }
```

I have tried various ways of setting up the templog.txt with -InputObject: using Get-Content, Get-Content -Raw, a variable, writing an array manually. I have also tried removing -NotMatch and using -eq $False for the output of select string.

Everytime though the output is just the contents of asy_files.txt (Reference File). It doesn't seem to care what is in templog.txt ($AsyFolder Output).

I have tried using compare-object/where-object method as well and it just says that both files are completely different.

Comment: PLEASE, do not post images of code/errors/data. since you posted an _image_ of the data, the only way to test code against that data is to type in _what you already have as text_. please replace the pictures of data with the actual text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Compare text files and show differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402629/powershell-compare-text-files-and-show-differences)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402629/powershell-compare-text-files-and-show-differences answers the question `I am trying to compare the contents of two text files and have only the differences be outputted to the console.`

Comment: Thank you for the advice Lee, I tried following some of the links, and found that one file had excess whitespace after the text. I ran some code to delete the whitespace and that helped, but it is still not behaving as expected. IE it still outputs every line from the reference file to the console. when it should only be writing as2.art, tpm.art, and xyp.txt

Comment: @PaulRd - to have S-O send a notice to a specific person, you need to use `@UserName` - as i did with this msg. [*grin*]

Comment: @PaulRd - you say that you want only the differences ... but your 3 items in your comment do not seem to do what you describe. for instance, there is no `As2.art` item in _either_ list. PLEASE, add all the needed info to your Question. burying it in the comments is too easy to overlook.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Lee_Dailey for your help in figuring out how to properly ask a question...

It ended up being additional whitespace (3 tabs) after the characters in the reference file asy_files.txt.
It was an artifact from where I copied from, and powershell was seeing `"as2.art"` and `"as2.art               "` I am not 100% as to why that matters, but I found that sorting for any whitespace with `/S` that appears after a word character `/W` and removing it made the comparison logic work. The Compare-Object|Where-Object worked as well after removing the whitespace.