# Find and replace several lines of text with an Batch File?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have parameter files (text files) which are always filled with different values. It's approx. 1500 Lines. Between this lines is a set of 30 lines which is always the same and this I would like to manipulate with batch file.

So for example.

This is the current file.

```
1 different value
2 different value
3 different value
4 different value
5 fixed value
6 fixed value
7 fixed value
8 different value
9 different value
```

But I would like to exchange it like.

```
1 different value 
2 different value 
3 different value 
4 different value 
5 EXCHANGED value 
6 EXCHANGED value 
7 EXCHANGED value 
8 different value 
9 different value
```

Perhaps also to add more text because its not always on the same position. The Text which get exchanged is always the same, but the position in the rows can move a little.

--

```
@echo off set "replace=something" set "replaced=different"
   
   set "source=Source.txt" set "target=Target.txt"
   
   setlocal enableDelayedExpansion ( for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in
   ('findstr /N "^" %source%') do ( set "line=%%b" if defined line set
   "line=!line:%replace%=%replaced%!" echo(!line!
```

I found also already some code which i modifyed, but this works only for single words. If i try to do more he simply ignores the ones before.

---

I worked again a bit on it..
But its not really doing what i want.

Source_File ; the file where i the text inside what the batch is should looking for (exact)
Traget_File ; the file where what i want in the end with the exchanged lines. (final)
Search_For ; This is a line inside where the starts to exchange.
Exchange_With ; the file with the new Lines.

Dont be made about the not proper working progress bar, i simply like it :P

```
SET "Source_File=D:\SEARCH.para"
SET "Target_File=D:\A.para"
SET "Search_For=//______________DATA_______________"
SET "Exchange_With=D:\TARGET.para"

set i=10
(Set /P j=...Please wait) < NUL
ECHO.
(Set /P j=..............................) < NUL

:Start
call :DisplayProgressBar %i%
set /a i = i + 1
if /i %i% leq 100 goto start

ECHO.
ECHO.

IF NOT DEFINED Search_For (ECHO Failure: Variable Search_For not set!&GOTO :eof)

IF EXIST %Target_File% (DEL /f %Target_File% 1>NUL 2>NUL)

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('FINDSTR . "%Source_File%"') DO (
SET Line=%%i& CALL :Exchange !Line!
)
GOTO :NEXT

:Exchange
SET Line=!Line:%Search_For%=%Exchange_With%!

IF [!Line!] EQU [] (ECHO.>>%Target_File%) ELSE (ECHO !Line!>>%Target_File%)
GOTO :eof

:NEXT
del "%Source_File%"
move /y "%Target_File%" "%Source_File%"

:DisplayProgressBar
(Set /P j=.) < NUL
title %1%% Completed
exit /b
```

Comment: How can you define if **`The Text which get exchanged`** is what you need? Why? And how do you want to process this text: replaced text is static; replaced text may vary by source text?

Comment: Hello Thank you for your replie :)

The part of the text inside the file is always the same, the part which should get inside is normally also the same. Here it would be good to have perhaps a sample.txt with the text which should get newly (replaced the old) inside the file, that i could adapt it.

Comment: So **sample.txt** contains searched text: `fixed value...`. **Target.txt** -exchange text: `EXCHANGED value..` **Input.txt** - parsed file. If lines with `fixed value` occur only once. You may use simple way to find its position number: `findstr /n /g:sample.txt input.txt`. So you can print all lines before this position to new **output.txt**. Then add **target.txt**. Then add last text of **input.txt**. Batch commands can help you do this job: `findstr.exe`, `for`, `more`, `>>`

Comment: Thank you very much for this support.
It really sounds like a good catch, i will give it a try and let you know. :) Thank you.

Comment: This task can be solved by `Windows batch`. Powershell [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402629/) looks more pretty.

Comment: This i can imagine, but i guess it will be for me more complicated then batch already hehe, but i will have alook aswell. Thank you for the advise.

Comment: I worked again a bit on it.. 
But its not really doing what i want.

Source_File ; the file where i the text inside what the batch is should looking for (exact)
Traget_File ; the file where what i want in the end with the exchanged lines. (final)
Search_For ; This is a line inside where the starts to exchange.
Exchange_With ; the file with the new Lines.